# Selenium -- Trying to access some fields

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to access the login and password fields in this simple page [stepik](https://stepik.org/login).

I have tried different ways:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

binary_yandex_driver_file = './initializer/yandexdriver.exe' # path to YandexDriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_yandex_driver_file, options=options)
driver.get('https://stepik.org/login')
```

Find element by name:

```
id_box = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
```

Find element by id:

```
id_box = driver.find_element_by_id("id_login_email")
```

Find element by XPath and by full XPath:

```
id_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//*[@id='id_login_email']")).click()

id_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/input[1]").click()
```

And in all the cases I was getting something like:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="login"]"}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the explicit wait for that. The problem happens in your case because the page is not loaded fully and you are trying to locate your fields.

Here is the working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stepik.org/login")
id_box = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id_login_email")))
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Excuse me, I still need a small help from you, let's say I have a contest link, which requires the person to login then enter, the ```login``` button is now on the toolbar, I am trying to do it,  but It didn't work, the link is something like [contest](https://stepik.org/lesson/113286/step/1), Could you please check it ?

Comment: @Josh, do you want to click on the "Log in" button on the toolbar (header of the page)?